# java - Usage of 'of' keyword when defining a method

Tags: java, keyword, reactor

In the Reactor code I could see something like

```
/**
 * Create a {@link Tuple1} with the given object.
 *
 * @param t1   The first value in the tuple.
 * @param <T1> The type of the first value.
 * @return The new {@link Tuple1}.
 */
public static <T1> Tuple1<T1> of(T1 t1) {
    return new Tuple1<T1>(t1);
}
```

What is this 'of' keyword?

Comment: That is the name **of** the method.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I love it when answers get recursive like that :)))))))))))))))))

Comment: Damn! You are right! I just overlooked and was wondering what is this 'of'. Thanks

Comment: sloppy naming convention

Comment: @user2310289 Huh, I thought it was used somewhat (though I admit, those two aren't necessarily mutually exclusive).

Comment: Usually methods names should be descriptive

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are seeing is not a new `of` keyword. It is actually the name of the method, even though it may not seem like it.